# Analog ground and pgnd in proteus

Tags: ground, proteus

I am doing a project on proteus,I cannot find the ground terminal, where can I find AGND(Analog ground) and PGND in proteus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the left hand menu of Proteus, go to the "Terminals" tab and you'll find the symbols for power, ground, input, output and others. connect this to your circuit and simply re-name the net to PGND or AGND

[image]

Comment: oh, I thought because have different functions so cannot use that ground. so is it possible to use just rename only?

Comment: You need a GND reference pint for the circuit to simulate correctly, so you'll need these. You can then just rename the nets